# $multiply only supports numeric types, not string while multiplying quantity * price , mongodb error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to multiply the quantity of products * price of an item. But I get `$multiply` only supports numeric type, not string while executing the program.

Here is the code:

```
let total = await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).aggregate([
                {
                    $group:{
                        _id:null,
                        total:{
                            $sum:{
                                $multiply:['$quantity','$product.Price']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]).toArray()
            console.log(total);
            resolve(total[0].total)
        })
```

Here I match the `userId` and it unwinded the products table after the I projected item and its quantity.

And I lookup the table and take details of that product after that I project again and take the quantity and item . Then I use group and set the id to null and then I try to access the total amount of the item so I used the `$multiply` for that.

**total:**

```
{
   $sum:{
        $multiply:['$quantity','$product.Price']
     }
 }
```

Here I needed to multiply the item quantity with price of that item.

eg: 2 * 20000 and get the total of 40000

Here I used database `mongodb` and `node.js` for executing the program

And I am getting the error like:

```
(node:12276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: $multiply only supports numeric types, not string..
```

Comment: convert type to integer using $toInt, $toDouble, $toLong, like this `$multiply:[{ $toInt: '$quantity' },{ $toInt: '$product.Price' }]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to convert the quantity and price into corresponding integer datatype. We can convert integer, double long datatype by using $toInt, $toDouble, $toLong
Here we need to change this as:
`$multiply:[{ $toInt: '$quantity' },{ $toInt: '$product.Price' }]`